# why is my mvc controller not picking up all my values from knockout client side on post

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, repository-pattern, single-page-application

I am using knockout and I have put a breakpoint on my post method and its capturing all my observables correctly , however when the data crosses over to the controller
server side (after clicking save button) only two of my values are being passed in from server side. So I put a break point on the controller and it seems to be picking up the drivers name and maintenance periodsand the rest of the values are just zero
Maintenance Periods is list for when the car should be serviced 30 , 60, 90 days and so on......  this is how I am posting to the controller from knockout NB note that my masterViewModel is my index.js and I am not trying post the make and the model just yet I only need the values from my saveInfo method

```
function driverVM() {
    var drv = this;

    drv.driverId = ko.observable(0);
    drv.driverName = ko.observable("");
    drv.currentServicePeriods= ko.observable([]);
    drv.pastServicePeriods =ko.observable([]);


}
function  vehicleVM{
    vvm.regNumber = ko.observable(0);
    vvm.make = ko.observable("");
    vvm.model = ko.observable("");
    vvm.DriverDetail = new  DriverVM();




vvm.saveVehiclDriverInformation = function () {
        if (!masterViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;

        vvm.DriverDetail;
        vvm.SaveInfo = $.map(masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM., function (item) {

            return masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.driverID, masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.driverName, $("#vehicleID").val(), $("#modelType").val(), masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.currentServicePeriods, masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.pastServicePeriods
        });


        $.when(postSecureData("/api/vehicleInfo/", ko.toJSON(vehicleVM.driverVM.SaveInfo)))
          .done(function () {
              document.getElementById("save-vehicleINfo-btn").innerHTML = "Saving...";
              setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("save-vehicleInfo-btn").innerHTML = "Save" }, 2500);
              $.msgGrowl({
                  type: 'info',
                  title: 'vehicle information',
                  text: 'vehicle details succesfully saved',
                  position: 'bottom-right',
                  lifetime: 3000
              });

          })
    };
```

Comment: there are a lot of error-generating leading and trailing periods all through this code. do you have a stripped-down fiddle that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @dperry no fiddle at the moment but if you can point out the  error-generating leading and trailing periods that I need to adjust that would be great

Comment: "all through" may have been an exaggeration, but there are a couple: the SaveInfo map call, the $.when line, and I thought there was one more, but can't seem to find it

Comment: @dperry $.when works fine perhaps its the saveInfo like u say  that should be replaced with another type of call not sure which type however

Comment: this `ko.toJSON(.vehicleVM.driverVM.SaveInfo)` should not work, the leading period in front of vehicleVM will break stuff

Comment: @dperry yes I removed that was a typing error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88659/discussion-between-anchor-and-dperry).

Answer (score 0):

Few things going on here.
It seems to me that `ko.toJSON(vehicleVM.driverVM.SaveInfo)` and `SaveInfo` are not needed as defined. SaveInfo would be better suited as a normal wrapper function to produce an object, like below:

```
vvm.saveVehiclDriverInformation = function () {
    if (!masterViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;

    function prepareInfo(){
        return {
            driverID: masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.driverID(),
            driverName: masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.driverName(), 
            vehicleID: $("#vehicleID").val(), 
            modelType: $("#modelType").val(), 
            currentServicePeriods: masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.currentServicePeriods(), 
            pastServicePeriods: masterViewModel.vehicleVM.driverVM.pastServicePeriods()
        }
    };



    $.when(postSecureData("/api/vehicleInfo/", prepareInfo()))
      .done(function () {
          document.getElementById("save-vehicleINfo-btn").innerHTML = "Saving...";
          setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("save-vehicleInfo-btn").innerHTML = "Save" }, 2500);
          $.msgGrowl({
              type: 'info',
              title: 'vehicle information',
              text: 'vehicle details succesfully saved',
              position: 'bottom-right',
              lifetime: 3000
          });

      })
};
```

Comment: thanks @dperry so far after trying your methods I am getting [object Object] , [object Object] , [object Object] , [object 
Object] , [object Object] , [object Object] , [object Object] , 
[object Object] ,

Comment: sorry, they need to be evaluated, one minute

Comment: oh, there are a few seemingly unnecessary things going on

Comment: Well your method does seem to be close to being correct as it is indicating match number of objects however they appear to be empty somehow "object Object". ???

Comment: I forgot to evaluate them again, one sec

Comment: knockout evaluation; parens. I already updated the code, try again